# asp.net label currency format

Tags: asp.net, currency

Hi how do format my label to a currency format.

code

```
lblFundsAvail.Text = result.Data.FundsAvail.ToString();
```

thanks

Comment: What is the type of `FundsAvail`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the format specifier `C`:

```
lblFundsAvail.Text = result.Data.FundsAvail.ToString("C");
```

Note though that this will use whatever currency the server happens to have as its current culture, and this may not be the currency you want. You can specify another culture as the second parameter.

Comment: How, after almost a decade, is this answer so obscure and with so few votes? Seriously the best, most concise answer I could find. Upvote #3 for you, sir!